# Vue.js - Can't properly validate a custom single file component with v-for using vee-validate

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, custom-component

I've been building a vue app and I'm currently building a component that has a "Person" object, and a few inputs fields to add information about that person, such as Name, address, email, etc. One of those fields is the mobile number, but a person can have more than one number, so I created a custom component that repeats the input field at will. This is roughly what it looks like. All those inputs are being validated using [vee validate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate). This is roughly what is looks like:

```
     <!--createPerson.vue -->
     <div class="form-group">
        <input v-model="person.firstName" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-delay="500" name="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First name">
        <span v-show="errors.has('first-name')" class="input__error">{{ errors.first('first-name') }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input v-model="person.lastName" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-delay="500" name="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
        <span v-show="errors.has('last-name')" class="input__error">{{ errors.first('last-name') }}</span>
    </div>

    <repeatable-inputs v-model="person.mobiles"  v-validate="'required'" data-vv-value-path="input" data-vv-name="mobile" type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" :inputmode="numeric" link-name="mobile number"></repeatable-inputs>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input v-model="person.email"  v-validate="'required|email'" data-vv-delay="500" name='email' type="text" placeholder="Personal email">
        <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="input__error">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
    </div>
```

The person object, under the same createPerson.vue file, has a property called mobiles which starts as an empty array. It also has a validateAll() function, used as described in the vee-validate docs, that performs a validation of all inputs when clicking a "Next" button.
Then, on the repeatableInputs.vue, there's this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
            <input
                :type="type"
                :name="name+index"
                :placeholder="placeholder"
                :inputmode="inputmode"
                :value="input"
                @input="update(index, $event)"
                v-focus></input>

        </div>

        <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="add">Add another {{linkName}}</a>


    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: {
                value: {
                    type: Array,
                    default: ['']
                },
                type: {
                    type:       String,
                    default:    "text"
                },

                name:           String,
                placeholder:    String,
                inputmode:      String,

                linkName: {
                    type:       String,
                    default:    "input"
                }
            },

            data: function () {
                return {
                    inputs: this.value
                }
            },
            methods: {
                add: function () {
                    this.inputs.push('');
                },

                update: function(index, e) {
                    this.inputs[index] = e.target.value;
                    this.$emit('input', this.inputs);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

To be able to validate these custom inputs in the parent createPerson.vue, using the validateAll() function, the docs state that I must, quoting, `Should have a data-vv-value-path attribute which denotes how to access the value from within that component (Needed for validateAll calls)`.

And this is where I got stuck. I'm not sure that that vv-path must point to, and I tried using 'value', ' input', 'inputs', creating a watch function, and a few other things that didn't even make much sense. I've found a git issue with validating custom inputs that used v-for, but that has apparently since been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Data-vv-value-path should point to where the data is inside the component state. On your input you can bind the input content to data with a v-model -attribute and then the validator knows which property of the child component it needs to validate.

So data-vv-value-path points to the data inside the child component and the data will be automatically updated when bound with v-model.

Comment: In my case, where would that be ? I've really tried everything I know so I feel like I'm missing some key concept here.